# Web browser rendering problems

Tags: google-chrome, rendering

I have a Sony Vaio and everytime I log into Yahoo the page comes up totally vertical. Everything from pictures to mail to news is listed vertical so i have a home page 10 pages long.I use Google and Google Chrome as my home pages but have some email on Yahoo and after I set up Google Chrome and some exts this Yahoo page started showing up vertical. The Google pages are ok but the print is now smaller but now some other web pages have started showing up vertial - CNN and Hufington. I run Norton and have no virus or internet problems I know about an ran a check yesterday. I was told to use the Alt gr key and the up aror to change the graphics and to rotate the screen but that does not work and I have no Altgr key marked so not sure I a even doing it correctly. Yikes!Can anyone help???

Comment: Does it also happen in Internet Explorer, or Mozilla Firefox? Does it happen when you disable or remove your plugins? If removing plugins helps, re-enable one by one, then restart Chrome after each one to see if the problem re-appears. Clear your browser caches. Does it still happen afterwards? Log in as another user account (create if necessary) and check to see if that account is also affected.

Answer (score 0):

If its *everything* being turned 90 degrees (which i understand to be the case from someone telling you to use alt up) , and the vaio is running an intel video chip, try ctrl alt up.

If its just websites, its seriously unusual - are you running a proxy, and is there any chance someone is playing a trick on you?

Alternately - Does this happen with other browsers? Does this happen in safe mode, with all the extentions turned off? (and what extentions?)

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one website that is giving you problems (and it sounds like it is) then it is most likely a CSS related issue - the local cached copy of the site's CSS may be corrupt in some way.

I would try clearing out all your temporary internet files - it differs on each browser how you do that.